# Smarty unable to write to template_c with .htaccess and mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, smarty

I'm using this block of code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.?]+)$ /content%{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

to make my urls look "prettier" so instead of domain.com/content/file.php it's just domain.com/file

My PHP file that calls my smarty template is in the content directory. I have changed my permissions recursivly on template_c to 777 and still I get the error message "Smarty: unable to write file /.../templates_c". When I move the php file out of the content directory and access it at domain.com/file.php, Smarty works perfectly. How can I keep my php files in the content directory with the mod_rewrite in place and still be able to use Smarty?

Comment: Have you used $smarty->setCompileDir to set the location of templates_c or you're using the default configuration?

Comment: I'm using the default. I also have an index file that is not in the content folder, so want that functionality to remain as well. Can smarty compile in multiple locations?

Comment: So does domain.com/content/templates_c exist? or only domain.com/templates_c?

Comment: only domain.com/templates_c so far. Perhaps if I created that folder in content and changed the permissions on that, it would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to create templates_c and the cache folders inside my content folder with the appropriate permissions. I tried it, it works! Thank you to Borgtex for getting me on the right track.